# Problem with value? and system/words/var in Rebol

Tags: rebol

Why does clipboard and system/words/clipboard points to 2 different value ?

```
>> clipboard
** Script Error: clipboard has no value
** Near: clipboard
>> system/words/clipboard
>> value? 'clipboard
== false
>> value? 'system/words/clipboard
== true
>>
```

Then how can I use value? within a func which uses clipboard as refinement if I can't test it on system/words/clipboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value? in system/words 'clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
unset? system/words/clipboard
```

but this is hack, Gregory's solution is more elegant.

Comment: It's not a hack, but it only works if you know that `clipboard` exists in `system/words`.